# v8 : visual studio release compilation static lib error: lld-link: error: could not open 'obj/v8_wrappers.lib': no such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, v8, static-linking, embedded-v8

i followed all the steps from https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn
to build release-static v8 lib but I'm getting this error :
using VC 2019 , win10 64bit from https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn
doing git branch it shows :

```
c:\Dev\my\v8\depot_tools\v8\v8>git branch
* (HEAD detached at origin/master)
  master
```

the error I'm getting :

```
c:\Dev\my\v8\depot_tools\v8\v8>python tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release
c:\Dev\my\v8\depot_tools\v8\v8>ninja -C out.gn/x64.release
ninja: Entering directory `out.gn/x64.release'
[1/1] Regenerating ninja files
[206/2990] LINK bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe.pdb
FAILED: bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe.pdb
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- ..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\bin\lld-link.exe /nologo -libpath:..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\lib\clang\12.0.0\lib\windows "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" /OUT:./bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe /PDB:./bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe.pdb @./bytecode_builtins_list_generator.exe.rsp
lld-link: error: could not open 'obj/v8_wrappers.lib': no such file or directory
[207/2990] LINK torque-language-server.exe torque-language-server.exe.pdb
FAILED: torque-language-server.exe torque-language-server.exe.pdb
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- ..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\bin\lld-link.exe /nologo -libpath:..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\lib\clang\12.0.0\lib\windows "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" /OUT:./torque-language-server.exe /PDB:./torque-language-server.exe.pdb @./torque-language-server.exe.rsp
lld-link: error: could not open 'obj/v8_wrappers.lib': no such file or directory
[208/2990] LINK torque.exe torque.exe.pdb
FAILED: torque.exe torque.exe.pdb
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- ..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\bin\lld-link.exe /nologo -libpath:..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\lib\clang\12.0.0\lib\windows "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" "-libpath:..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" /OUT:./torque.exe /PDB:./torque.exe.pdb @./torque.exe.rsp
lld-link: error: could not open 'obj/v8_wrappers.lib': no such file or directory
[215/2990] CXX obj/test/unittests/cppgc_unittests_sources/member-unittest.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```